# C# WinForms - Code works before array, but when placed after array it fails

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to append a piece of text to a RichTextBox, using the following code
`Form2.codeOutput.Text += "test";`
This works fine when placed before my array (like this):

```
public static void newString(string curLine)
        {
            Form2.codeOutput.Text += "test";

            string[] parsedString = new string[3];
            parsedString[0] = "string";
            parsedString[1] = curLine.Substring(7, 12);
            parsedString[2] = curLine.Substring(23, curLine.Length);
        }
```

However, when I place it after my array, it doesn't work:

```
public static void newString(string curLine)
        {
            string[] parsedString = new string[3];
            parsedString[0] = "string";
            parsedString[1] = curLine.Substring(7, 12);
            parsedString[2] = curLine.Substring(23, curLine.Length);

            Form2.codeOutput.Text += "test";
        }
```

I tried searching for solutions but I didn't get any good results; any help would be appreciated.

***Edit 1: I should add that when the code doesn't work, it doesn't give an error or crash or anything; the text simply doesn't appear in the richtextbox.***

***Edit 2: I tried the same except I replaced the `Form2.codeOutput.Text += "test";` with `Debug.WriteLine("test");`, same issue; the code works when placed before the arrays but not after.***

Comment: did you run in to any exceptions?  it looks like that might be what's happening here..  place a breakpoint on the first line inside of your method and step through it and see what happens

Comment: some issue with your subStringMethod, you can sort this issue by putting Debug.WriteLine("<YOUR SPLITED DATA>") this below every array element assignment. what happend when you debug this code?

Comment: @psj01@Biju Kalanjoor I found the issue, the first two work fine but the third one gives "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException"

Comment: try adding     curLine = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";    is the first statement of your newString method. if this works fine, next step you varify the value in the curLine parameter . and check with quick watch of each subString statement

Comment: @BijuKalanjoor I tried that, however I'm getting System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException. I don't know why though, since curLine is 36 chars long.

Comment: Yes, thats why the last statement didn't execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public static void Main()
{
    string value="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
    newString(value);
}

public static void newString(string curLine)
{
     string[] parsedString = new string[3];
     parsedString[0] = "string";
     parsedString[1] = curLine.Substring(7, 12);
     Console.WriteLine(parsedString[1]);
     parsedString[2] = curLine.Substring(23); // Changes here
     Console.WriteLine(parsedString[2]);

     Console.WriteLine("Done");
     //Form2.codeOutput.Text += "test";
}
```

Check the values in the array.

This method can arise ArgumentOutOfRangeException in two conditions:

if the parameters startIndex or length is less than zero.
If startIndex + length indicates a position which is not within current instance.

Comment: The important bit here is the `curLine.Substring(23)` because the second paramter is the length of the substring, not the last index.

Answer (score 0):

What is value of "curLine" you pass into method?
If startIndex is less than zero or greater than the length of this instance, Substring will throw ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Comment: curLine is "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890" -- it's just a placeholder value I'm using to test out stuff.

Comment: `parsedString[2] = curLine.Substring(23, curLine.Length)` change to 

`parsedString[2] = curLine.Substring(23, curLine.Length - 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Ok that's fun. Easy peezy. First things first: always start with the docs!!

Secondly, Substring's second paramter is the length of the requested substring, not the last index desired. Do `curLine.Substring(23, curLine.Length - 23);` and you should be good. Right now you're telling substring to start at index 23 and give you the next curLine.length characters. Obviously that fails because it's not 23 + curLine.length  characters long.

From the docs @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-5.0#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_

```
Substring(Int32, Int32)
Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a specified character position and has a specified length.

public string Substring (int startIndex, int length);

Parameters:
startIndex
Int32
The zero-based starting character position of a substring in this instance.

length
Int32
The number of characters in the substring.
```